# Why isn't overflow checked by default

Tags: java, c, integer-overflow

I found some questions on SO about checking operations before executions for over/underflow behavior. It seems that there are ways to do this quite easy. So why isn't there an option to automatically check each mathematical operation before execution or why is there not Exception for <s>buffer</s> over/underflow of arithmetic operations? Or phrased differently: In what scenario would it be useful to allow operations to overflow unnoticed?

Is it maybe a matter of run-time? Or is the main source of overflow occurring during non-mathematical operations?

Comment: Firstly, buffer overflow and arithmetic overflow are two completely different things. One argument for not checking *every* operation is that it would be very costly yet in many cases completely unnecessary (for example, if an operation cannot overflow due to preconditions).

Comment: In C, operations that result in overflow/underflow have undefined behaviour in a lot of cases.   Which, among other things, means that a compiler is not required to check operations.    Having every operation checked - particularly at run time - would involve a performance hit.   And a developer usually has more information (e.g. understanding of the overall algorithm) so is better placed to decide which operations are critical.   Theoretically at least ..... too many developers don't think about such things at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, for C there are checking options, see here: http://danluu.com/integer-overflow/

As for java, adding integer overflow checks would open a can of worms. As java does not offer unsigned types, unsigned math is often done in plain int or long types - obviously the VM will not be magically aware of the unsigned nature of the operation intended, meaning you either need to add unsigned types or the programmer would need to pay a lot of attention to turn the checks on/off. An example for unsigned math with signed types can be found in Arrays.binarySearch. On a side note, Java does exactly define what the result in case of overflow is, so relying on overflow behavior is legal use of defined behavior.

As briefly analyzed in the C link above, these checks can have a severe impact on performance in practice, due to a combination of crude implementation and/or by interfering with other code optimizations.

Also, while most CPU's can detect overflow (usually by the C and V flag), they do it simultaneously for signed/unsigned (common CPU ISA's do not make a distiction between signed/unsigned operations in case of add/sub). Its up to the program to respond to these flags, which means inserting additional instructions into the code. Again this means the programmer/compiler has to be aware if the operation is intended to be signed or unsigned to make the correct choice.

So overflow detection does come with a cost, albeit it could be made reasonably small with good compiler support.

But in many cases overflows are either not possible by design (e.g. the valid input parameters of a function cannot produce overflow), desired (e.g. wrap around behavior counters), or when they do happen are caught by other means when the result is used (e.g. by array bounds checking).

I have to think hard for instances where I actually ever felt the need for overflow checking. Usually you're far more concerned to validate the value range at specific points (e.g. function arguments). But these are arbitrary checks for a function specfic value range, which the compiler cannot even know (well, in some languages it would, because its explicitly expressed, but neither Java nor C fall in this category).

So overflow checking is not universally useful. It doesn't mean there aren't any potential bugs it could prevent, but compared to other bugs types overflow isn't really a common issue. I can't remember when I last saw a bug caused by integer overflow. Off by one bugs are far more common, for example. On the other hand, there are some microoptimizations that explicitly rely on overflow wraparound (e.g. an old question of mine, see accepted answer: [Performance: float to int cast and clipping result to range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922759/)).

With the situation as described, forcing C/Java to check and respond to integer overflow would make them *worse* languages. They would be slower, and/or the programmer would simply deactivate the feature because it gets in the way more than it is useful. That doesn't mean overflow checking as a language feature would generally be bad; but to really get something out of it, the environment also needs to fit (e.g. as mentioned above, Java would need unsigned types).

TL;DR It could be useful, but it requires much deeper language support than just a switch to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The Java language just does not have this feature built-in as a keyword or mechanism to apply directly for the `+`, `-` and `*` operators. For example, C# has the `checked` and `unchecked` keywords for this. However, these checks can be **costly** and hard to implement, when there is no native support in the language. As for Java 1.8, the methods [`addExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-), [`subtractExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#subtractExact-int-int-) and [`multiplyExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-) have been added to the API to provide this feature, as pointed out by [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) in the comments.

Why is this not done *automatically* even if the language supports it? The simple answer is that in general over- and underflow can be accepted or wanted behaviours or they simply do not occur because of a sophisticated and well executed design **as it should be**. I would say that exploiting over- and underflows is rather a low-level or harware programming concern to avoid additional operations for performance reasons.

Overall, your application design should either explicitly state the **sensible** use of arithmetic over- and underflows or better not need to use them at all, because it can lead to confusion, unintuitive behaviour or critical bugs. In the first case you don't check, in the second case the check would be useless. An automatic check would be superfluos and only cost performance.

A contrived example of a wanted overflow, could be a counter. Say you have an unsigned short and count it up. After 65536 it goes back to zero because of the overflow, which can be convenient.

Comment: *"Java just does not have this feature built-in."* Java provides an API: [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-), [multiply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-) and [subtract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#subtractExact-int-int-).

Comment: @Tom Thank you for your remark. What I meant was that the Java language does not define a keyword or mechanism like e.g. C# does, so that you can use `+`, `-` and `*` as usual. It is worth mentioning that the API was added not until Java 1.8, too. Edited, credits to you.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer two potential factors as to why unchecked arithmetic is the default:

- *Sense of familiarity:* Arithmetic in C and C++ is unchecked by default and people who got used to those languages would not expect the program to throw, but to silently continue. This is a misconception, as both C and C++ have undefined behavior on signed integer overflow/underflow. But nonetheless, it has created a certain expectation in many people's minds and new languages in the same family tend to shy away from visibly breaking established conventions.
- *Benchmark performance:* Detecting overflow/underflow usually requires the execution of more instructions than you would need if you decided to ignore it. Imagine how a new language would look like if a person not familiar with it wrote a math-heavy benchmark (as it often happens) and "proved" that the language is dramatically slower than C and C++ even for the simplest mathematical operations. This would damage people's perception of the language's performance and it could hinder its adoption.